# How to enable dragging and resizing of divs across table cells and rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, jquery-ui

**UPDATE**

I am thinking Jquery is the only solution to my problem. So making the demo work would be a big help. Thank you.

I am trying to create a scheduler type application.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I need to be able to resize the colored divs vertically and also drag them to any row/cell in the table.

Example. Drag resize orange div into row beneath it.

[image]

Or in this case if I resize the Green div the yellow div needs to be pushed into the row beneath it.

[image: IMAGE 2]

Dragging divs is self-explanatory.

I have a working sandbox [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-template-forked-1u4dt?file=/Example.js)

I did find a fiddle online that has exactly what I need but it uses Jquery and I would prefer not to use it if possible. [FIDDLE OF WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR](http://jsfiddle.net/texas697/wqj4an5v/1/)

```
   $(function() {
      $(".drop").sortable({
        connectWith: "td",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
      }).disableSelection();
    });

    $(function() {
      $(".resize").resizable({
        grid: [50, 0],
        handles: 'e'
      });
    });
```

Comment: You could try [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) for drag and drop. Still, the behavior of pushing elements to the next cell or covering multiple cells sounds a little more complex, like you want the elements to be independent of the grid and just clip to the cells if possible, perhaps similar to google calendar?

Comment: Yes it is a challenging task. Not really sure how to make it work. I'm having a hard time placing the activities at a specific location that matches their actual date.

Comment: It's basically a scheduler / calendar. But I haven't found one that actually would be able to meet my requirements

Answer (score 4):

### Vanilla JS solution

You said:

> I did find a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/texas697/wqj4an5v/1/) online that has exactly what I need, but it
> uses jQuery and I would prefer not to use it if possible.

I tried to replicate the output of the fiddle mentioned above using vanilla JS ([HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)). This is the closest that I could get.

*Note: Change `resize: horizontal;` to `resize: vertical;` if you want to resize boxes vertically.*

See the snippet below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var dragSrcEl = null;

  function handleDragStart(e) {
    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
  }

  function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

    return false;
  }

  function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add('over');
  }

  function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over');
  }

  function handleDrop(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    if (dragSrcEl != this) {
      dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
  }

  function handleDragEnd(e) {
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.classList.remove('over');
    });
  }

  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.container .drop');
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    item.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  height: 100px;
}

td {
  height: 68px;
  width: 150px;
  border: gray thin solid;
}

.resize {
  top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: #002DA4 thin solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  z-index: 1;
}

td.drop {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table cellspacing='3'>
      <tr>
        <th>8am</th>
        <th>9am</th>
        <th>10am</th>
        <th>11am</th>
        <th>12n</th>
        <th>1pm</th>
        <th>2pm</th>
        <th>3pm</th>
        <th>4pm</th>
        <th>5pm</th>
      </tr>

      <tbody class='container'>
        <tr>
          <td class='drop'>
            <div draggable='true' class='resize'>Session A</div>
          </td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'>
            <div draggable='true' class='resize'>Session B</div>
          </td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
          <td draggable='true' class='drop'></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so I am thinking the only way to make this work is to actually use jquery. Any chance you could get the demo working with it?

Comment: @texas697 Please note Stack Overflow asks you not to use edits to reply to the author.

Comment: Sorry about that. Was trying to edit my original post

Comment: Hi @Rok Benko, first thank you for your contribution. How can we place session B beside A if user drop in TD where A is already there? And How can we only allow to drag horizontally, I mean to restrict to drag div&td outside table or raw ?

Comment: @R.Baraiya You're welcome. :) Regarding horizontal drag see this: https://jsfiddle.net/5snrqyvL/7/.  Regarding placing two `div`s inside the same cell, it's far more difficult to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @RokBenko for your quick reply.  Here I am working with three div inside one row. do you think its possible to resize this div from left side as well ? I tried the different resize values, didn't work. does matter if divs are overlaped or nested.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here. With jQuery. Looks like an elegant implementation.

[Draggable, Movable and Resizable HTML DOM elements using jQuery](https://www.encodedna.com/2013/08/draggable-resizeable-html-dom-elements-using-jquery.htm)