# How to drag the div to another columns inside table?

Tags: angular

I am try to use this answer from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011071/how-to-enable-dragging-and-resizing-of-divs-across-table-cells-and-rows), the issue is not able to drag and drop the div

I tried to the code in `ngOnInit` as below, not working

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {});
    });
  }
```

Comment: really a solution based in jQuery or in JS is not a good approach.... anyway **not** use addEvenListener('DOMContentLoaded'). Check the [Component lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). From the docs, I'm pretty sure you need add the code in ngAfterViewInit -without the addEventListener-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by the point angular executes the code inside ngOnInit the DOM has already loaded, so the event never executes. to replicate what the code you linked does you can simply remove this event listener, and add the rest of the code to ngAfterViewInit (adding the event listeners to the proper elements, using getElementBy or other selector), that's the hook angular use when the page has finished loading.

be aware of the differences between working with vanilla JS and Angular, sometimes there's a better alternative to doing things in the framework.

in your case I would probably look into binding events to functions in the components.
https://angular.io/guide/event-binding